# pyTelegramBotAPI register_next_step_handler с inline клавиатурой

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

К примеру имеется бот со списком покупок и функциями добавления (1 шаг) и удаления (2 шага) продукта. Я его реализовал на обычной клавиатуре, но как передать и обработать в шагах inline клавиатуру?

**bot.py**:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('your_token')
user_dict = {}


class LIST:
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg
        self.del_pr = None


@bot.message_handler(commands=["list"])
def list(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True)
    bt1 = types.KeyboardButton('Добавить')
    bt2 = types.KeyboardButton('Удалить')
    bt3 = types.KeyboardButton('Отмена')
    markup.add(bt1, bt2, bt3)
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Список покупок:\n\nКартошка\nМорковка\nСелёдка\n\nЧто хотите сделать?',
                           reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, switch)


def switch(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        user_dict[chat_id] = LIST(message.text)

        if message.text == 'Добавить':
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True)
            bt1 = types.KeyboardButton('Отмена')
            markup.add(bt1)
            msg = bot.send_message(chat_id, f'Введите название продукта',
                                   reply_markup=markup)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, add_pr)

        elif message.text == 'Удалить':
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True)
            bt1 = types.KeyboardButton('Отмена')
            markup.add(bt1)
            msg = bot.send_message(chat_id, f'Введите название продукта',
                                   reply_markup=markup)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, del_pr)

        else:
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove(selective=False)
            bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Отмена!', reply_markup=markup)

    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))


def add_pr(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        user_dict[chat_id] = LIST(message.text)
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove(selective=False)
        if message.text != 'Отмена':
            bot.send_message(chat_id, f'Условно добавил {message.text}\n/list', reply_markup=markup)
        else:
            bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Отмена!', reply_markup=markup)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))


def del_pr(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        user = user_dict[chat_id]
        user.del_pr = message.text

        if message.text != 'Отмена':
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True)
            bt1 = types.KeyboardButton('Да')
            bt2 = types.KeyboardButton('Нет')
            markup.add(bt1, bt2)
            msg = bot.send_message(chat_id, f'Вы уверены, что хотите удалить {message.text}?', reply_markup=markup)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, really)
        else:
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove(selective=False)
            bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Отмена!', reply_markup=markup)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))


def really(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        user = user_dict[chat_id]
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove(selective=False)

        if message.text == 'Да':
            bot.send_message(chat_id, f'Условно удалил {user.del_pr}\n/list', reply_markup=markup)
        else:
            bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Отмена!', reply_markup=markup)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))


bot.enable_save_next_step_handlers(delay=2)
bot.load_next_step_handlers()
bot.polling()
```

Comment: Решился вопрос?

Comment: Нет, не решился

Answer (score 1):

Всё просто, замените:

```
bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, switch)
```

На:

```
bot.register_next_step_handler(msg.msg, switch)
```

Или на:

```
bot.register_next_step_handler(message.message, switch)
```

Таким образом, можно получить ответ от inline кнопки и передать его в:

```
register_next_step_handler
```

Строчку: `chat_id = message.chat.id`, можете удалить.

Answer (score 1):

В телеботе появились стейты. Они легче в коде, а также лучше по скорости. Они сохраняются или в файле, или же в памяти.

Смотрите пример:
https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/custom_states.py

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)